# How might one fundamentally define the difference between indefinite and definite nouns?

Tags: ontology, category-theory

I am exploring ologs, a way of diagramming conceptual relationships. I am trying to understand if it is necessary for the nodes or objects of an olog to should be restricted to represent only classes of things, or if there is no reason why the structure of an olog could be used in a more free way, with any kind of textual label. (This opens the question, regardless of the text labels, why are ologs useful, purely in terms of their mathematical and structural properties? The answer to that question can shed light on why their text labels should or should not conform to certain constraints.)

This has opened the question in my mind if there is an interesting way to construct the idea of “a specific entity” out of a system that begins only with the idea of “a class of entities”.

However, in set theory, it does not work this way. Assuming the existence of the empty set and a few basic mental operations (I am think of power sets, wand/set templates, maybe the axioms of ZFC), I am pretty sure it works in the reverse direction - we start with “entities with specific identity” (sets), and build an idea of “the class of all entities sharing a property” (restricted set comprehension).

This post touches on stuff I have been learning for a little while so I realize it’s probably not that easy to understand; I can come back and try to spell it out more clearly.

The question is basically, in what ways have people tried to rigorously define what it means to be “a specific cat”, rather than, “cats in general”?

(I’ll try to answer my own question at least partially in a second.)

Comment: Is it sufficient to say something like "Sets with a known/knowable number of elements?" You can imagine formally specifying "this cat" as "A cat satisfying the following conditions: they are the closest cat to me, and their fur is white and black, and their name is Meowsers". Or "Those deer" as "The set of deer satisfying: I can see them, and they are over there, and there are 3 of them." This invokes the subject and their knowledge about the world, but I think that's an integral part of definiteness anyways?

Comment: That is absolutely one approach and that’s the kind of thinking I’m kind of asking about. I feel like you understand the question, anyway. A much simpler/pithier but less clear way of asking it is, “Can you construct a language of particulars out of a language of universals, or do you have to assume the existence of particulars a priori”? I mean, predicate logic assumes the existence of quantification over variables a priori, I think, so there’s an example of the latter rather than the former. I thought about my own approach a little bit today.. might share some ideas later.

Answer (score 4):

Sets and ZFC is a good meta theory to adjust to the notion of collections as conceptual metaphors (cf. Lakoff's Metaphor of Containment). But **sets were, IMNSHO, superseded by types, and [type theory (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/) is a much better model for [natural language ontology (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-language-ontology/)**.

If you're interested in modeling [concepts (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/concepts/) and going beyond definitions of necessity and sufficiency, (see the [SEP's Definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/) and Robinson's *Definitions* if you haven't), **I'd recommend an intro book on NLP.** [Einstein's *Introduction to Natural Language Processing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_to_Natural_Language_Process/72yuDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) is rather contemporary, and it covers everything from [endophora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endophora) to [dynamic semantics (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/search/search?query=dynamic%20semantics).

My biases are to accept Brouwer's advocacy and see the world through the lens of [intuitionistic type theory (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/). This means that I view an articulation of concepts in line with a constructivist epistemology. Ideas are not discovered nor are they invented, but rather they are constructed. It's a long-running question about how much our language affects our conscious experience, and I'm more inline with the logical positivists on this point, but you might also be interested in concepts like [linguistic relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity), [quantifier variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_variance), and [formal semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_semantics_(natural_language)).

If you really are gung-ho you might want to start with a topic like [donkey sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_sentence). They're a fascinating glance into how we codify meaning with formalisms. Other relevant topics are [Montague's Grammar](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/montague-semantics/) (historical) or Ranta has a [type-theoretic grammar](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Type_theoretical_Grammar/6kZiAAAAMAAJ?hl=en) built on Martin-Löf's work.

Comment: There’s definitely some really good contextualization of some of my thoughts here. You might be interested in joining this chat room for category theorists: https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/join/wwbjjc6ewz7dpd4hhswhyfbn/

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. I am a fan of category theory. I didn't actually answer your question, btw. A cat and the cat differ by the later is an unspecified reference: the latter construction usually carries with it an implicit set of predicates: the cat (which...)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some relevant ideas it is important to get a clear grasp of first, I think.

## Problem 1: Are sets models of things, or are objects constructions of sets?

An elementary introduction to set theory says that a set is just “a collection of things”, and those things could be anything. I could have a collection that includes the color red, the person Mark Twain, and a yucca plant. The idea here is that sets are a kind of cognitive-structural abstraction of one of the most fundamental ideas imaginable to give order or meaning or structure to a world, that is, the ability to thing of some things *together*, and call that grouping a *thing* in its own right. (For this reason, I have considered that if I were to ever write my own presentation of set theory, I would simply title it “Some Things”.)

On the other hand, ZFC does not do this. Assuming the existence of the empty set, various approaches in set theory build universes of new sets from the previously existing ones. This is interesting. It is never said that the initial empty set is actually just a denotation for “some thing”. It would be hard to think of it that way, since it is empty. If it represented a real world thing, maybe it could be “nothingness”. But that interpretation doesn’t seem congenial to our purposes, because then all the new sets we build are just nested boxes on “nothingness” - it’s not like we build interesting concepts like “dogs” by complex nesting of the concept of “nothingness” (in saying it, I suppose that claim can be challenged, though.)

So this to me is the first problem. We usually use sets as models of something else. But I do not yet see how actually rigorous or axiomatic definitions of set theory allow this - the potential of sets to *denote*. Because when you build cumulative hierarchies of sets, you are just building sets that contain other sets. The idea of some “abstract element” is not available.

This is not the case in logic, fortunately. In logic, we can take as primary a *variable*, which we say ranges of a *domain of discourse*.

I will think more about this.